# flash as3 dynamic instance variable name / concatenation

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, variables, dynamic, instance

I have an array of project type codes like this:

```
project_types_array[0] = "p"
project_types_array[1] = "exp"
```

etc.

and a corresponding set of movie clips, exported for actionscript, with names:

```
type_p
type_exp
```

etc.

I want to somehow dynamically attach a movieclip on the stage according to the project type that exists in the array. I could just do something like this:

```
for ( var i in project_types_array) {
    if (project_types_array[i] == "p"){
        var clip_p = new type_p();
        container.header.type_loader.addChild(clip_p);
    }
}
```

but I'd rather do something like this:

for ( var i in project_types_array) {

```
var "clip_" + project_types_array[i] = new "type_" + project_types_array[i]();
container.header.type_loader.addChild("clip_"+project_types_array[i]);
```

}

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
var c:Class = getDefinitionByName('type_' + project_types_array[i]);
var spr:c = new c();
```

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#getDefinitionByName%28%29

Comment: If I try this - I get the following errors: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: typeClass.
Implicit coercion of a value with static type Object to a possibly unrelated type Class.

Comment: @mheavers - where are the clips stored?

Comment: the clips are in my flash library and given a class name at runtime, and attached from the library. Does that answer your question www0z0k